# Dynamic content and rewrite URLs

Tags: url-rewriting

I want create one page with the name *Home*. In this page I will write title:

**Find wedding services in `[STATE]`**

and the content. Now, if the URL is `example.com/new-york`, the title will be:

**Find wedding services in `New York`**

Or if the the url is `example.com/new-jersy`, the title will be the same just in the end "*New Jersy*". I will write all the cities of US in the sitemap so it will help to index.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of the Insert PHP plugin: https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/

You would have to bind the URL path as a `$_GET` parameter in the .htaccess using RewriteCond/RewriteRule (if you want to keep your URL structure) or use a structure that is something like `domain.com?city=New York`.

In your WordPress post, you'd be able to include something like:

```
[insert_php]
echo 'Find wedding services in ' . $_GET['city'];
[/insert_php]
```

As for the SEO side, make sure you don't have the same contents on each page as Search Engines give penalties for duplicated contents.

Comment: Hi Marc,  Thanks for the reply, I know that it's not SEO place, but there is any idea how to avoid this SEO issue ? As I write in 1 page. @Marc-Anroine Parent

Comment: @Haviv the good practice would be to have different content on each page (given your line of work, maybe the wedding venues should be different per city). Search engines value real, human generated content, so your automatic pages, if only the title changes from the URL, would not be considered good practice.